# Is it possible to generate an ICS file in Javascript and then pass it via webcal: url?

Tags: javascript, icalendar, webcal

I am aware that it's possible to generate an ICS file and prompt the user to download it via javascript:

https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js

And it is possible to set up a webcal url that points to an ICS file hosted on the internet, such as:

webcal://ical.mac.com/ical/US32Holidays.ics

But is it possible, without server-side intervention, to give the user a webcal url that uses the dynamically generated ICS? I would like to generate a dynamic calendar event in my front-end javascript application and would ideally not involve a backend in the process.